# Is it possible to put controls such as ListView/TextBox etc.. in a Viewport3D

Tags: wpf

I have a model in a Viewport3D and I want to draw a textbox next to it, and the textbox, can 'regular' control be added to Viewport3D ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the XAML Below, I've created a Viewport3D with some 2D controls, a textblock and a textbox in a horizontal stack panel, the control you were looking for is the Viewport2DVisual3D you'll need to describe it's geometry and material but after that it'll be usable in world space.

the best thing about the Viewport2DVisual3D control is that it unprojects mouse actions back in to world space meaning that the controls you place into the viewport are still usable just as if they were drawn in 2D.

```
<Viewport3D>

    <!-- To look in to a 3D world you need a camera just like a game.-->
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
        <!-- 
        I've positioned the camera at the center of the world and moved it back
        Along the Z axis, try changing the numbers here to see how it works.
    -->
        <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 3"/>
    </Viewport3D.Camera>

    <!-- All 3D worlds need to have a light, you can again play with the values
        here to see what they mean, Directional light is one that starts at a 
        location in the world and shines in a given direction.
-->
    <ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
            <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>

    <!-- 
    This is the wonder control that allows you to display WPF controls 
    in a 3D model.
-->
    <Viewport2DVisual3D >

        <!-- 
        The 3D model is made up of a vertex list, each grouping of 3 digits
        in the positions property is a point on a polygon, here I've used
        4 points to represent a flat square surface (2 triangles to make the square)
        and relate to a bitmap produced from your WPF controls 
        Triangle TriangleIndices map positions in to triangles, here I've got 
        1             2 imagine a triangle drawn through points 0, 1, 2
                        and another drawn from 0, 2 and 3 

        0             3
        The texture coords tell the 3D viewport how to map your controls visual to the 
        points in positions, texture coordinates range from 0,0 top left to 1,1 bottom right
    -->
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3" TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

        <!-- Here I'm doing a transform, it's the same as simply rotating a control using it's render transform
            in WPF
    -->
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
            <RotateTransform3D>
                <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                    <!-- Play around with the Axis numbers to see what they mean.-->
                    <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="-45" Axis="1, 0, 0" />
                </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
            </RotateTransform3D>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>

        <!-- This is the 2D bit, inside the visual property you can place any WPF controls. -->
        <Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <!-- This bit is obvious. -->
                <TextBlock Text="3D user interface!"/>
                <TextBox />
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
    </Viewport2DVisual3D>

</Viewport3D>
```

Comment: Sorry for the seriously patronising comments, I actually wrote this as the answer to another question which was then deleted so can't just link to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a canvas above your Viewport3D:

```
<Grid>
  <Viewport3D>
    [..]
  </Viewport3D>
  <Canvas>
    <TextBox />
  </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

It depends of what you want to make.